# How to achieve Text masking background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[image: example of desired behaviour]

How can I achieve this effect in Flutter programmatically?
I've tried `ShaderMask` but didn't find the right tool yet.

Blue background in my case is a `ClipPath` on a `Container`.
Both, `Text` and `Container` are in the `Stack`, so the text is `Positioned`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is quite simple: place two widgets in a `Stack`. At the very bottom is `Text` with blue color, and on the top goes `ClipPath` with white color `Text` as its child (both `Positioned` exactly the same).

The tricky thing is, to position white text inside `ClipPath` the same way, you'll need to wrap this text in another `Stack` and `Positioned`.